# Unexpected indent - Python def

Tags: python, python-2.7

can you help me with this?

```
def group_iter (iterator, n=2, strict=False):

    accumulator = []
        accumulator.append(item)
        if len(accumulator) == n: 
        yield tuple(accumulator)
        accumulator = []

    if strict and len(accumulator) !=0:
        raise ValuseError("Leftover values")


print "This is count %r " % group_iter
```

and when I run it I get:

```
accumulator.append (item)
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: there's no indentation after `if len(accumulator) == n: ` and many more.

Comment: your formatting is all wrong.

Comment: There's no reason to indent your code after `accumulator = []`.

Comment: +1 to neutralize the downvotes. it's a simple question, but it's not a bad question. the OP is a python newbie, that's all

Comment: your code doesnt work, at all. even with the indent errors fixed, what exactly are you trying to do? where does `item` come from? `strict` isnt even used.... please review some basic python tutorials and come back with something a bit more sensible.

Comment: @gefei: Indentation is central to Python, and the first thing you learn in tutorials. The error message points out where the indentation is wrong as well. This question shows a distrubing lack of research effort.

Answer (score 0):

You have indented your code too far, remove the extra space to match the indentation of `accumulator = []`.

```
def group_iter (iterator, n=2, strict=False):
    accumulator = []
    accumulator.append(item)
    if len(accumulator) == n: 
        yield tuple(accumulator)
        accumulator = []
```

You may want to review your python tutorials as to when to indent python code, and when not to.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the error show the line number too? It should give you a hint of where to start. (Its on lines 4-7 btw)

```
accumulator.append(item) # remove indent
if len(accumulator) == n: # remove indent
    yield tuple(accumulator) # keep indent
accumulator = [] # uncertain whether to keep or remove this base on your needs.
```